# Howto obtain Newline in Tool Tips

Tags: visual-studio-2008, string, mfc

My App is MFC based and uses the CToolTipCtrl to implement Tool Tips.  The Tool Tips are in a string table resource and each tool tip is loaded with LoadStringW. Try as I might I cannot get the Tool Tips to display over multiple lines.  Each tool tips is displayed as a single line.

I tried adding \r\n &\n /\r/\n to the middle of a tool tip string but nothing works.

Example:

In the string table

```
IPD_TT_ACC_ID Please enter the account id.\r\n The account ID can be obtained from the Helpdesk
```

Should be displayed as:

> Please enter the account id.
>  The
>   account ID can be obtained from the
>   Helpdesk

But is displayed as:

> Please enter the account id. The
>   account ID can be obtained from the
>   Helpdesk

Comment: The output examples show the problem and are correct.  I want the output on 2 lines but always get one.

Comment: \n does not work. Tried that first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved that problem in the past by using [SetMaxTipWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc8843k4(VS.80).aspx) method.

Example:

```
 m_ToolTipCtrl->SetMaxTipWidth( 300 ); // for multiline messages
```

Comment: I can confirm this. Without SetMaxTipWidth only the first sentence was displayed. With SetMaxTipWidth it worked as intended.